# Refreshig php data with jQuery not working

Tags: php, html, jquery

I wanted to continuously refresh PHP data using jQuery as it gets updated in the database. At first I used the jQuery load function and it worked spectacularly. But I needed to refefresh several `div` elements, so I decided to switch to this code below:

```php
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <?php
        echo '<span>Test Message</span>';
    ?>
</div>
<script>
    $.get("/test.php", function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        $("#test").html($data.find("#test > *"));
    });
</script>
```

The code above is a sample. The text disappears after the script gets executed. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Use `append()` and not `html()`

Comment: @Taplar, yes! this worked. If you add this as an answer, i'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `html()` method does a complete replacement of all contents of the parent(s).

If you instead want to add more content, then use the `append()` method instead.

If you want to add more content, but want to add it to the beginning and not the end, use `prepend()` rather than `append()`.